# wp_remote_request/cURL response timeout unless ran from command line (WP CLI)

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Problem: wp_remote_get/wp_remote_request of a specific https target fails to return a response unless ran via WP_CLI function.

```
$wp_remote_args => array(
'timeout' => 5,
'sslverify' => true,
'blocking' => true,
'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0',
'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Authorization' => '...',
    'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8; text/plain',
    'Host' => '...',
    'Origin' => '...',
    'Referer' => '...',
),
)
wp_remote_request($url, $wp_remote_args)
```

I can only assume that something is perceived differently from the remote server when the GET request is received from standard PHP processing vs WP_CLI. Other wp_remote_request URLs are sent and received without issue.

Increasing the timeout has no impact on getting a response in this scenario.

Comment: Did you solve this? Which was the problem?

Comment: Sadly, no. This never did get resolved.